# Bad education or hypnotism

Tags: sin

There was a virus that miseducated my loved one and is controlling his mind. No matter what he does it comes back.It taught him things against Islam.

Will my loved one be held accountable if the virus tells him to do things he doesn't want to do by Allah?

Answer (score -2):

What kind of virus it is. So far I know there is no such virus that can mislead a Human.

**except for zombie virus** that do not exist.